# How to implement autoretry for Celery tasks

Tags: python, celery

In Celery, you can `retry` any task in case of exception. You can do it like so:

```
@task(max_retries=5)
def div(a, b):
    try:
        return a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError, exc:
        raise div.retry(exc=exc)
```

In this case, if you want to to divide by zero, task will be retied five times. But you have to check for errors in you code *explicitly*. Task will not be retied if you skip `try-except` block.

I want my functions to look like:

```
@celery.task(autoretry_on=ZeroDivisionError, max_retries=5)
def div(a, b):
    return a / b
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I searched this issue for a while, but found only [this feature request](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1175).

I decide to write my own decorator for doing auto-retries:

```
def task_autoretry(*args_task, **kwargs_task):
    def real_decorator(func):
        @task(*args_task, **kwargs_task)
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except kwargs_task.get('autoretry_on', Exception), exc:
                wrapper.retry(exc=exc)
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator
```

With this decorator I can rewriter my previous task:

```
@task_autoretry(autoretry_on=ZeroDivisionError, max_retries=5)
def div(a, b):
    return a / b
```

Comment: This loses the result though. Shouldn't it return something?

Answer (score 15):

Celery (since version 4.0) has exactly what you were looking for:

```
@app.task(autoretry_for=(SomeException,))
def my_task():
    ...
```

See: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions

Comment: upvoted! how do you add an exponential backoff to this, since the exception will be handled by celery it seems

Comment: @PirateApp presumably the Celery 4 retry backoff args are supported for autoretry too http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.retry_backoff

Comment: Is the code sample you provided supposed to retry indefinitly `my_task()` in case an exception is raised? I can't make it work :(

Comment: @Florent you can set a maximum number of retries with `retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 5}`

Answer (score 2):

I've modified [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979656/1787372) to work with the existing Celery API (currently 3.1.17)

```
class MyCelery(Celery):
    def task(self, *args_task, **opts_task):
        def real_decorator(func):
            sup = super(MyCelery, self).task

            @sup(*args_task, **opts_task)
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    func(*args, **kwargs)
                except opts_task.get('autoretry_on', Exception) as exc:
                    logger.info('Yo! We did it!')
                    wrapper.retry(exc=exc, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return real_decorator
```

Then, in your tasks

```
app = MyCelery()
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(autoretry_on=Exception)
def mytask():
    raise Exception('Retrying!')
```

This allows you to add the autoretry_on functionality to your tasks without having to use a separate decorator to define tasks.

Comment: shouldn't it have a `return` inside `wrapper` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of the existing answers.

This fully implements the Celery 4.2 behaviour (as [documented here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.autoretry_for)) but for Celery 3.1.25.

It also doesn't break the different task decorator forms (with/without parentheses) and returns/raises properly.

```
import functools
import random

from celery.app.base import Celery as BaseCelery


def get_exponential_backoff_interval(factor, retries, maximum, full_jitter=False):
    """
    Calculate the exponential backoff wait time.

    (taken from Celery 4 `celery/utils/time.py`)
    """
    # Will be zero if factor equals 0
    countdown = factor * (2 ** retries)
    # Full jitter according to
    # https://www.awsarchitectureblog.com/2015/03/backoff.html
    if full_jitter:
        countdown = random.randrange(countdown + 1)
    # Adjust according to maximum wait time and account for negative values.
    return max(0, min(maximum, countdown))


class Celery(BaseCelery):

    def task(self, *args, **opts):
        """
        Overridden to add a back-port of Celery 4's `autoretry_for` task args.
        """
        super_method = super(Celery, self).task

        def inner_create_task_cls(*args_task, **opts_task):
            # http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.autoretry_for
            autoretry_for = tuple(opts_task.get('autoretry_for', ()))  # Tuple[Type[Exception], ...]
            retry_backoff = int(opts_task.get('retry_backoff', False))  # multiplier, default if True: 1
            retry_backoff_max = int(opts_task.get('retry_backoff_max', 600))  # seconds
            retry_jitter = opts_task.get('retry_jitter', True)  # bool
            retry_kwargs = opts_task.get('retry_kwargs', {})

            def real_decorator(func):
                @super_method(*args_task, **opts_task)
                @functools.wraps(func)
                def wrapper(*func_args, **func_kwargs):
                    try:
                        return func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
                    except autoretry_for as exc:
                        if retry_backoff:
                            retry_kwargs['countdown'] = get_exponential_backoff_interval(
                                factor=retry_backoff,
                                retries=wrapper.request.retries,
                                maximum=retry_backoff_max,
                                full_jitter=retry_jitter,
                            )
                        raise wrapper.retry(exc=exc, **retry_kwargs)
                return wrapper
            return real_decorator

        # handle both `@task` and `@task(...)` decorator forms
        if len(args) == 1:
            if callable(args[0]):
                return inner_create_task_cls(**opts)(*args)
            raise TypeError('argument 1 to @task() must be a callable')
        if args:
            raise TypeError(
                '@task() takes exactly 1 argument ({0} given)'.format(
                    sum([len(args), len(opts)])))
        return inner_create_task_cls(**opts)
```

I have also written some unit tests for this as am using it in my project.

They can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anentropic/e159cc864592d02d2e8936b355b5eaf1) but note they are not easily runnable - treat more as documentation of how the above feature works (and validation that it works properly).